# inserting and retrieving array into mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a form with an array of something like this:

Address[addr1], address[addr2], address[pin] etc..

How can I insert and retrieve this into database? anyhelp will be greatly appreciated.

```
<pre><input placeholder="Street Address" type="text" name="address[addr1]" /><span class="icon-place"></span></span></pre>
```

Comment: Is the form method get or post? that will determine how the you collect the data. I added an answer but now re-looking at your question i see you made an edit

Comment: Maze, you really answered my question and it was as simple as breathing

Comment: No prob. glad to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to validate your input fields to prevent sql injection.
But below should put you on the right track. I edited my answer. try this.

```html
<?

$lineOne = $_POST['address[addr1]'];
$lineTwo = $_POST['address[addr2]'];
$pin = $_POST['address[pin]'];

//form sql statement
$sqlSet = "INSERT INTO addressTable(address1, address2, pin)
        VALUES('$lineOne', '$lineTwo', '$pin')";

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// execute insert query
$insertQuery = mysqli_query($con, $sqlSet);


//form sql statement
$sqlGet = "SELECT * FROM addressTable";

// execute select query
$selectQuery = mysqli_query($con, $sqlGet);

?>
```

Comment: Don't use mysql_query - use mysqli instead. mysql* has been deprecated.

Comment: try to echo $lineOne before you move ahead to make sure it gets your addr1 input

Comment: Thank you maze runner.. it worked and you explained it so simple. being a PHP learner I could easily understand your code. Also thnak you peter for your advcie and thanking everyone for their help

Comment: glad you are moving forward. dont forget to give my answer a vote if it helped you. @vinayKR

Comment: ah no worries. just answer a few questions in your field or expertise. At least you solved your issue, the vote is not so important

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$address1=$_POST['Address'][addr1];
$address2=$_POST['Address'][addr2];
$pin=$_POST['Address'][pin];

$query=mysqli_query($link, "insert into your_table(address1, address2, pin) values('$address1', '$address2', '$pin')";
```

try this process

Comment: Hello Nahid, Thank you for your quick reply. my phpstorm says "undefined constant addr1 ". So  I want to give more info.... in the form it is exactly defined like this.... name="address[addr1]"  this is where my confusion is. I'd the idea of using array in the form that you had mentioned, but unfortunately it doe not work.

Answer (score 0):

**For Insertion:**

Method 1 : use json_encode($address) and save data. [See detail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Method 2 : try foreach() then insert data like

```
foreach($address as $a){
   //query for insertion
}
```

**For Retrieve data**:

For Method 1 : use json_decode() to decode all json data. [See detail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Method 2 : normal process how you retrieve data

```
foreach($address as $a){
   //query for insertion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using data from users it's pretty important to `prepare` statements rather than just putting them into building the SQL query as a string to avoid injection attacks.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO addr_table (addr1, addr2, pin) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $addr1, $addr2, $pin);

    $address1=$_POST['Address']['addr1'];
    $address2=$_POST['Address']['addr2'];
    $pin=$_POST['Address']['pin'];

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

(Some of the `close` business isn't as necessary, but is there for completeness.)

Comment: Hello Peter, Thank you for your answer and quick comments. I am trying to analyze the code you have given as I am still a learner, but its really helpful. Regards